# Rust Piston can't find correct type hint

Tags: rust, rust-piston

I am New to Rust and come from another programming language.

here are my dependencies

```
[dependencies]
piston_window = "0.123.0"
piston = "0.53.1"
gfx = "0.18.2"
```

I am having a problem with the manual type hinting

when I load a Texture without adding a type hint the texture is loaded and can be displayed in the window.

```
let dirt = piston_window::Texture::from_path(&mut window.create_texture_context(),
Path::new("assets/sprites/dirt.png"), Flip::None, &TextureSettings::new()).unwrap();
```

when I try to manually add the type hint which vscode recommends me, I get an Error.
e.g

```
let dirt: Texture<Resources>= piston_window::Texture::from_path(&mut window....
```

The Error can be reproduced by running the following main file in an environment with a dummy.png file

```
extern crate piston_window;
extern crate piston;
extern crate gfx;
use piston_window::{
    PistonWindow,
    WindowSettings,
    Flip,
    TextureSettings,
    Texture,
};

use std::path::Path; 

fn main(){
    let opengl_version = piston_window::OpenGL::V3_2;
    let mut window: PistonWindow = WindowSettings::new("test", [1280., 720.]).exit_on_esc(true).graphics_api(opengl_version).build().unwrap();
    let working = piston_window::Texture::from_path(&mut window.create_texture_context(), Path::new("dummy.png"), Flip::None, &TextureSettings::new()).unwrap();
    let failing:Texture<gfx::Resources> = piston_window::Texture::from_path(&mut window.create_texture_context(), Path::new("dummy.png"), Flip::None, &TextureSettings::new()).unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual type is `Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources>`, not `Texture<gfx::Resources>`.

Note that [`gfx::Resources`](https://docs.rs/gfx/latest/gfx/trait.Resources.html) is a trait, not a type.  In `Texture<R>` the `R` generic type must not be covariant, and even if it were the type would likely need to be `Texture<dyn gfx::Resources>`.  While it's true that `gfx_device_gl::Resources` implements `gfx::Resources`, that doesn't on its own imply that `Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources>` and `Texture<dyn gfx::Resources>` are compatible types.  (The `R` type parameter would also need to be covariant.)

If you want to ensure that `failing` is a `Texture` without giving a particular resource type, you could use the annotation `Texture<_>` instead, which permits the compiler to infer `Texture`'s generic type argument.

---

Further reading:

- [The Rustonomicon - Subtyping and Variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html)